# VSTS fails when it gets to my gulp task when run against my local agent

Tags: node.js, git, gulp, azure-pipelines-build-task

So I went through all the steps outlined in the documentation in order to setup a local build agent for VSTS.  VSTS sees and even runs my 'npm install' build step without failures.  However, when it tries to run the gulp step that will run against my Gulpfile.js it fails with the following error message: "Not found node: null"

If gulp cannot find node then how did the npm install command, which runs a postinstall of 'npm install typings gulp jspm -g' work?

Very strange stuff, right?

this is VSTS with a git repo.

Comment: What's the detail code of Gulpfile.js.

Comment: Task         : Gulp
Description  : Node.js streaming task based build system
Version      : 0.5.29
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613721)
==============================================================================
Not found node: null

Answer (score 0):

Try to install them without -g argument. On the other hand, you may update/install latest version of NodeJS.

Comment: The gulp tasks run fine when I run them from the local command line.  When they run with the vsts agent they don't run.  Why would it matter how they ran when they are running on the same system?

Comment: @edgarhsanchez Is the account of build agent the same as your account? By default, it uses service account.